# Recyclerview adapter keep selected item only and remove all items except selected in android

Tags: android

If anyone know how to show in recycler view adapter selected items only that means i need to show only selected item and remaining items i want remove or hide.

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

   private List<Movie> moviesList;
   // Start with first item selected
   private int selectedItem = 0;
   int selectedPosition=-1;


  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, year, genre;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);


   public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
      this.moviesList = moviesList;
   }

   @Override
   public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

      return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
       holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
       holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
       holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());


       if(selectedPosition==position)
          holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#50000000"));
       else
          holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          selectedPosition=position;
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(position,moviesList);

        }
    });
  }
  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
     return moviesList.size();
  }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried when user selected one item that one remains in current recycle view. then proceed to buy like that

Comment: Please provide details about your approach and code snippets for better answers. 
You may remove other items from your list and notify the adapter using. notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Please check the above code i added my adapter code . can u plz tell how to remove all data in adapter then keep selected item only in adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one boolean variable in Movie class:

```
     class Movie{
            private boolean isSelected =false;

            public boolean isSelected() {
                return isSelected;
            }

            public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
                isSelected = selected;
            }
        }
```

Initially this variable will be false onClick make it true:

```
      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    movie.setSelected(true);
                    removeUnSelectedItem();
                }
            });

        private void removeUnSelectedItem(){
                    List<Movie> temMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Movie movie:moviesList){
                        if(movie.isSelected()){
                            temMovieList.add(movie);
                        }
                    }

                    moviesList.clear();
                    moviesList.addAll(temMovieList);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

it will remove all unselected or un-click items & it will display only Clicked items.

Comment: Thanks vivek mahajan. Its really helpful to me.Its working awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Implements this interface into your activity like this:

ItemClickSupport.addTo(YourRecycleViewObject).setOnClickListener(this);

After you get onItemClick method in your activity and get selected position, with this position you get object from your list  and create new list with this object and set new adapter with another list.

```
package com.firebasechat.syscraft.firebasechat.Utils;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

import com.firebasechat.syscraft.firebasechat.R;


public class ItemClickSupport {
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        }
    };
    private View.OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                return mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener mAttachListener
            = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            }
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    };

    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support != null) {
            support.detach(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemLongClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }

    public interface OnItemLongClickListener {

        boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }
}
```